# Login as a guest

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authentication, login-control

I use Spirng Security to authorization. From main site I have two links - one to login form for registered users, second to page where user will be logged in as a guest. I couldn't find solution how login as a guest with spring security (without any password to put in but still logged in as GUEST ROLE. Is there something to be changed in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class or I have to add somehow username and password for "GUEST" in POST method and send to authorization?

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConsumingRestAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {@Autowired
private DataSource securityDataSource;
@Autowired
private SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/loggedIn/guest").hasRole("GUEST")
.antMatchers("/loggedIn/user").hasRole("USER")
.antMatchers("/loggedIn/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin()
.successHandler(successHandler)
.loginPage("/logginProcess/login-page")
.loginProcessingUrl("/logginProcess/authenticateTheUser")
.permitAll()
.and()
.logout()
.permitAll()
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.accessDeniedPage("/home/access-denied");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/home/**", "/");
}}
```

Comment: What is the difference between guest access and anonymous access?

Comment: Anonymous can't access any page at all

Comment: That is your configuration. The question is: why do you not use anonymous user as a guest?